# How to get the closest color to my color variable?

Tags: java, colors, rounding

I have a question regarding **Colors** and how to **Round** them. I need to be able to get the closest color to my color variable.

For example, I have a color that is similar to orange (**255, 119, 0**) and I need that to go through a process until it returns the actual color orange (**255,165,0**). I have no idea on, How I can implement this. Any help would be appreciated great.

Comment: You need to tell us more about the rounding logic and rules. How is a "target" color defined ? Is it a predefined set of colors ? Why 255,165,0 and not 255,120,0 which is also an orange color ?

Comment: I have everything setup. I have the color that needs to be rounded and the color that I want to round to. All I need is a method that can round a color.

Comment: A method needs definition. We can't help you much without it.

Comment: I'm trying to check if the color passed in is close to your goal color. So the method would have 2 color variables. One for the color and another for the goal color. This is the basic premise of the method I want.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you are trying to check if the color passed in is close to your goal color (aks orange in your example). Store each of the numbers in an array and compare them by looping through & if statements ...

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I'm looking for... could you give me an example of loops or if statements I would use?

Comment: sure, do you happened to have any code, or the problem statement or method..

Comment: I only have a empty method right now... Is that okay?

Comment: yes that's fine, I want to know if you want to return a boolean or int ...etc, and what parameters are given in the method

Comment: Just do a boolean right now I can change it later